# PHP: array_filter for an object?

Tags: php, object, laravel-5, array-filter

I have an array that I need to filter for certain things, for example, I might only want records that have the day of the week as Friday. As far as I'm aware this has never worked but it's taking an object and using `array_filter` on it. Can this work? Is there a better way or a way to do this on with object?

```
public function filterByDow($object)
{
    $current_dow=5;
    return array_values(array_filter($object, function ($array) use ($current_dow) {
        $array = (array) $array;
            if(!empty($array['day_id']) && $array['day_id'] > -1){
                if($array['day_id'] != $current_dow){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
    }));
}

$object = $this->filterByDow($object);
```

Sample data might be like:

```
$object = (object) array(['id' => '1', 'day_id' => 3], ['id' => '2', 'day_id' => 4]);
```

Comment: can u provide a sample data, so that i can simulate it in fiddler?

Comment: Sure. I've edited the question. thank you.

Comment: What exactly does not work with the given code? Why do you need to cast the inner array into an object?

Comment: It's part of something bigger which is very badly written but I'm just trying to figure out if this part should work or if there's a better way to do this to an object.

Comment: I have to make the variable `$array` an array because it's originally an object. Sorry for the confusing variable names.

Comment: What is the fucking point of having an object which is an array?

Comment: It's a laravel collection but the sample data is just there to describe it.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter :-) ?

Comment: You can cast an object to an array by doing $casted = (array) $someObject; then use array_filter() on that array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from the comments the array is a laravel collection I guess the answer is:

```
$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) { 
    return $value['day_id'] == 5; 
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    <?php
$items = array(['id' => '1', 'day_id' => 3], ['id' => '2', 'day_id' => 5]);
function filterByDow($items, $dow = 5){
    return array_filter($items, function($item) use ($dow) {
        if($item['day_id'] == $dow){
            return true;
        }
    });

}

$resultArr = filterByDow($items);
print_r($resultArr);
?>
```

Comment: An object is passed to filterByDow therfore I do not know if this change in the code is allowed?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, I have submitted an edit with very minor improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a collection and implement methods for filtering in it.

```
class Offer
{
    private $dayId;

    public function getDayId()
    {
        return $this->dayId;
    }

    public function setDayId($dayId)
    {
        return $this->dayId = $dayId;
    }
}

class OfferCollection
{
    const FRIDAY = 5;

    static $dayIds = [
        self::FRIDAY => 'Friday'
    ];

    private $offers = [];

    public function addOffer(Offer $offer)
    {
        $this->offers[] = $offer;
    }

    public function getOffersByDay($dayId)
    {
        $offers = [];

        if (in_array($dayId, self::$dayIds)) {
            foreach ($this->offers as $offer) {
                if ($offer->getDayId == $dayId) $offers[] = $offer;
            }
        }

        return $offers;
    }
}
```